# ¿Como darle una descripción / comentario a las columnas de una tabla en Base de Datos?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, db2

¿Se puede de alguna manera al crear una tabla en base de datos, darle una especie de texto de ayuda o descripción a las columnas creadas?
Creo a ver visto esto pero pude concretar mi búsqueda... alguien aqui que sepa?

un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE TablaDocumentada(
Nombre VARCHAR(30) [comando para comentar/describir o algo asi] 'Este campo es el Nombre del usuario',
cantH INT [helptooltipdescription] 'Campo para la cantidad de horas trabajadas'
....
)
```

Ok ok estoy con DB2.. Entonces tenemos que con COMMENT se le agrega un comentario y listo? y si ya esta creada uso el

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN [esquema.]tabla.columna IS 'comentario'
```

cierto?

Y se puede comentar al usar un ALTER? ejemplo:

```
ALTER TABLE TablaDocumentada ADD nuevaColumnaDocum varchar(5) comment 'una nueva columna con comentario';
```

--lo intente así y no me sirvió en db2
Usando el System i Navigator puedo ver las tablas y un texto que las acompaña describiendo su funcion eso se le puede dar directamente desde la aplicación pero hay manera de darle este texto desde la creacion de la tabla o la consulta? *porque no veo los comentarios que cree .. :( ni siquiera en el Dbeaver*--

**Falso lo anterior** acabo de reiniciar el Dbeaver y ahora si me muestra el Comment en el Campo Description.. parece que no estaba refrescando bien ... tuve que hacer la consulta y luego refrescar y ahí apareció. ¿Que puedo decir?.. mañas raras de los programas jeje

Gracias por su rápida respuesta, feliz día!

Comment: He modificado tus etiquetas, entiendo que estas hablado de `db2` no?

Answer (score 2):

Prueba colocando el comando COMMENT después de cada columna de la siguiente manera:

```
CREATE TABLE TablaDocumentada (
  Nombre VARCHAR(30) COMMENT 'Este campo es el Nombre del usuario',
  cantH int COMMENT 'Campo para la cantidad de horas trabajadas',
  ....
)
```

Fuente: [MySQL and comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199905/mysql-and-comments)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que lo que buscas es algo como esto?

COMMENT ... IS 'comentario'

No se con que  BD estes trabajando pero puede que buscando por aquí o agregando diccionario de datos en tu busqueda consigas algo mas!

https://ora.u440.com/ddl/comment.html

Answer (score 1):

Hola compañero te saludo y te comento que para agregar un comentario o descripción a cada columna de tus tablas prueba con el siguiente ejemplo saludos

```
CREATE TABLE pagos(
    id INT COMMENT 'para identificar el pago',
    pago VARCHAR(100) COMMENT 'para escribir de que fue el pago',
    CONSTRAINT pk_pagos PRIMARY KEY(id)
)ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Recuerda así mismo que en el lenguaje SQL se deben usar las comillas simples para declarar una cadena de texto

Saludos

Nota: Creado en MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar no está de más aclarar que [`COMMENT`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000901.html) sirve para comentar múltiples tipos de objeto del catalogo, la [documentación](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_10.0.0/admin/src/tpc/db2z_addandretrievecommentsfromcatalog.html) de IBM es bastante explicativa, si lo que quieres es comentar una columna de una tabla, podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN DSN8A10.PROJ.PRSTDATE IS
  'Estimated project start date. The format is DATE.';
```

Luego para recuperar este comentario:

```
SELECT REMARKS
  FROM SYSIBM.SYSCOLUMNS
  WHERE NAME = 'PRSTDATE' 
        AND TBNAME = 'PROJ'
        AND TBCREATOR = 'DSN8A10';
```

No has aclarado en que entorno estaría corriendo tu `db2` pero por lo que menciona [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40272273/6836377) respuesta, puede haber diferencias en la forma de acceder al catalogo.

- En Linux/Unix/Windows, esta consulta debiera recuperar los comentarios

  ```
  select tabname, tabschema, remarks from syscat.tables where tabname='EMP_VIEW1'
  select tabname, tabschema, colname, remarks from syscat.columns where tabname='EMP_VIEW1'
  ```
- En z/OS, esta otra.

  ```
  select name, creator, dbname, remarks from sysibm.systables where name='TABLENAME'
  select name, tbcreator, tbname, remarks from sysibm.syscolumns where tbname='TABLENAME'
  ```

Comment: saludos! ¿A que se refiere el hecho de recuperar un comentario? no entiendo muy bien el ejemplo..

Comment: @HeckDan, cuando digo recuperar, es leer el comentario que asignaste previamente a la columna.